# Using async in spawn_callback to write causes RuntimeError: Cannot write() after finish()

Tags: tornado

I'm trying to have a background process that runs every 10 secs to write some random stuff to the web page. The page load will trigger this background process once.
The async def do_something() works on print(message) but fails on the self.write(message)

I'm not sure if i should add the @tornado.gen.coroutine decorator to the do_something but tried that and got the trackback saying it was never awaited.

```
"""
Python 3.5
This is the MainHandler being called from the def main()
"""
class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        global background_flag

        self.write("Hello, world")
        # Coroutines that loop forever are generally started with spawn_callback()
        if not background_flag:
            print ("Launching spawn_callback ...")
            tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().spawn_callback(self.minute_loop)
            background_flag = True

    async def minute_loop(self):
        while True:
            # await self.do_something() #do_something must be an async def as well non-blocking
            await self.do_something()
            await tornado.gen.sleep(10)

    async def do_something(self):
        now = DT.now()
        now_str = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
        message = "[{0}] {1} : Running this".format(inspect.stack()[0].function, now_str)
        print (message)
        self.write(message)
```

i expect the web page to be updated with the message:
[do_something] 27/04/2019 23:42:08 : Running this
[do_something] 27/04/2019 23:42:18 : Running this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `spawn_callback`. Just convert the `get` method to an async coroutine and `await` on the `minute_loop`.

```
async def get(self):
    ...
    await self.minute_loop()
```

---

Note: A webpage is not supposed to be a long running connection. If you want to update the webpage with new data, you should consider websockets.

Comment: thanks! Yes i switched to using websocket whereby i launch a PeriodicCallback at open().